# Plot Circles / Polygons with KM radius from CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, table

I'm looking to plot a series of points with a set radius in google earth engine from a CSV. The `table.draw` function I'm currently using plots a pixel based radius, how can I convert this to a Km based radius?

After uploading my csv as an asset, importing into the console and using the following code to plot:

```
Map.addLayer(table.draw({color: 'FF0000', pointRadius: 5, strokeWidth: 5}), {opacity: 0.8});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps buffer your points with the number of meters you want your radius to be:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Geometry.Point([10, 0]),
  ee.Geometry.Point([10, 0.1]),
  ee.Geometry.Point([10, 0.2])
])

var buffered = table.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(5000, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(buffered.draw({color: 'FF0000', strokeWidth: 0}), {opacity: 10.8)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/802e3505dc4f737343a6db1a8ff9e32b

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much @Daniel!